# typo3 extend backend module templateRootPaths

Tags: typo3

I want to extend the redirects-Modul within my extension, especially the template path, but it's not working:

```
module.tx_redirects {
    view {
        templateRootPaths {
            0 =
            1 =
            200 = EXT:extkey/Resources/Private/Extensions/Redirects/Templates/
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell the path of your overwritten template?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. you would need to [XCLASS](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Xclasses/Index.html) `\TYPO3\CMS\Redirects\Controller\ManagementController::initializeView`